# Remove an asp.net control from code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to remove a control (a textbox) from my page when a certain condition is verified.
Is it possible to do from code-behind or I need to use JavaScript.

**NOTE** I need to remove the control, not to hide...

Comment: Just remove it by ID from the Page controls collection.

Comment: When is your condition verified? Is it before/during page render? If not, you would indeed need javascript/DOM to accompish that without page reload.

Comment: @J.Hudler the condition is evalued during page_load

Comment: @davioooh: Even if you mention that you _need to remove the control, not to hide it_; do you know that it's not rendered at all on clientside (it's html is not generated) when it's invisible on serverside? So `TextBox1.Visible=false` means no textbox at all on clientside.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`Controls.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.remove.aspx) or [`Controls.RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.removeat.aspx) on the parent `ControlCollection`.

For example, if you want to remove all TextBoxes from the page's top:

```
var allTextBoxes = Page.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();
foreach(TextBox txt in allTextBoxes)
    Page.Controls.Remove(txt);
```

<sub>(note that you need to add `using System.Linq` for `Enumerable.OfType`)</sub>

or if you want to remove a TextBox with a given ID:

```
TextBox textBox1 = (TextBox)Page.FindControl("TextBox1"); // note that this doesn't work when you use MasterPages
if(textBox1 != null)
    Page.Controls.Remove(textBox1);
```

If you just want to hide it (and remove it from clientside completely), you can also make it invisible:

```
textBox1.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

While you could remove it from the controls collection, why not hide it instead?

```
yourTextBox.Visible = false;
```

This will prevent it from being included in the generated html sent to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

When you set `.Visible=false`, it will never be rendered in the page. If you remove the control from Controls collection, don't do it during `DataBind`, `Init`, `Load`, `PreRender` or `Unload` phases as it will throw exception.

Adding or removing control dynamically may result in problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just remove it from the controles collection of the page:

```
this.Controls.Remove(control);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on `Remove method`

```
this.Controls.Remove(YourControl);
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.controlcollection.remove(v=vs.80).aspx