# How to remove dynamically added controls in .net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I want to remove dynamically added user control

I tried but it is not removed

Code:

.ascx

```
<asp:Button ID="removebtn" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClick="removebtn_Click"  />
```

.ascx.cs

```
public event EventHandler UserControlButtonClicked;

public void OnUserControlButtonClick()
{
  if (UserControlButtonClicked != null)
  {
     UserControlButtonClicked(this, EventArgs.Empty);
  }
}

protected void removebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnUserControlButtonClick();
}
```

.aspx

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="New_Employee.aspx.cs" Inherits="Portal.New_Employee" %>
 <%@ Register Src="~/VisaUserControl.ascx" TagName="VisaUserControl" TagPrefix="uc" %>

 <div id="div1" runat="server">   
 <uc:VisaUserControl ID="VisaUserControl1" Visible="false" runat="server" />
 <asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate> 
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>              
 <asp:Button ID="btnAddVisa" runat="server" Text="Add More Visa" onclick="btnAddVisa_Click" width="76px" />
 </div>
```

.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VisaUserControl1.UserControlButtonClicked += new
             EventHandler(AddVisaControl_UserControlButtonClicked);
}

private void AddVisaControl_UserControlButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = (VisaUserControl)LoadControl(@"VisaUserControl.ascx");
    this.rpt1.Controls.Remove(ctrl);
}
```

**Edit:**

Here I am adding the user controls

```
  public List<string> NoOfControls
    {
        get
        {
            return ViewState["NoOfControls"] == null ? new List<string>() : (List<string>)ViewState["NoOfControls"];

        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["NoOfControls"] = value;
        }
    }


    protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);

        GenerateControls();
    }


    private void GenerateControls()
    {
        foreach (string i in NoOfControls)
        {
            VisaUserControl ctrl = (VisaUserControl)Page.LoadControl("VisaUserControl.ascx");

            ctrl.ID = i;
            this.rpt1.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        }
    }

    protected void btnAddVisa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> temp = null;
        var uc = (VisaUserControl)this.LoadControl(@"VisaUserControl.ascx");

        string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        uc.ID = id;

        temp = NoOfControls;
        temp.Add(id);
        NoOfControls = temp;
        rpt1.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
```

In the below image if I click Remove button I want to remove that row

[image]

Comment: "but I couldn't understand " is not a question.

Comment: I can't see any code for a dynamically added control, only a statically defined control in the ASPX. The last part of the code, you create a brand new control using `LoadControl(@"VisaUserControl.ascx")` and then attempt to remove it from a collection that is most certainly wasn't a member of.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but you may be able to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802588/delete-asp-net-control-from-code-behind
It wasn't exactly what I needed.